# Do words "iron" and "irony" have anything in common?

Tags: etymology

I understand that the word [*irony* comes from Greek *eironeia*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=irony) and [*iron* comes from Old English *isærn*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=iron), but there should be something more to it. Why are both words so similar in modern English? Any thoughts, theories?

Comment: @acattle: This kind of assertion is pretty common -- someone once tried to convince me that Greek *trauma* and German *Träume* were somehow cognate based on their forms. But to dismiss these connections out of hand is to dismiss horizontal transfer-like mechanisms, whereby diachronically unrelated words can still influence each other.

Comment: @jogloran I guess I did sound a bit dismissive and I do think this question deserves a legitimate answer (which is why I suggested migrating) but even so the author hasn't really offered any rational for these words being related (I just assumed due to homophony). I'd encourage the author to make an edit to their post explaining in detail while they think there might be a connection but as of right now I see no connection at all between the words (other than the aforementioned homophony).

Comment: Sometimes there really are coincidences.

Comment: This could be a good question, with the right approach.

Comment: Similar with _pull_ and _pulley_ and many more, especially [style and stylus](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf)

Comment: Although English does have many homonyms (or near-homonyms) it's hard to find examples with completely unrelated etymologies. I wonder how common they are.

Comment: @dainichi: I suspect there are a large number.  I cannot see the word *areal* without wanting to read it as "a-real" (unreal) rather than the intended "area-l".

Comment: Given that these two words seem to be traceable back to Proto-Indo-European **were*, meaning to speak and **eis*, meaning strong, it seems unlikely to be anything more than coincidence.

Comment: I once heard a joke that goes: *if Burglars commit burglaries and Felons commit felonies, then God is an Iron.*

Comment: I think it is ironic that iron and irony have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 8):

You are describing by example how folk etymologies get started: requiring in your own mind that there be a reason behind a coïncidence.